# Using vector::back() to modify vector element

Tags: c++, vector, reference, c++14

I have the following struct:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct A {
    std::string name;
    int id;
};
```

And a vector containing A elements:

```
std::vector<A> a_vector;
```

I am trying to append an element to the vector and change its values using the following:

```
void test()
{
    A a;
    get_a(a);

//Up to this point I thought modifying this a object would mean modifying the back element of the vector. But it doesn't work as planned, doing this:

    a.id = 2; //Doesn't modify the id of the element in the vector. 
}
```

where get_a is defined as : (The code is simplified, in the real one I really need to pass a as argument and not get it as return)

```
void get_a(A& a) //This function normally assigns a in different ways
{
    a_vector.emplace_back();
    a = a_vector.back();
}
```

How can I do to have the a element be the same as the one in the vector? Do I really have to use pointers?

Comment: because you are making a copy of it A a; says that. Use referenece: A &a = a_vecotr.back();

Comment: Why the downvotes? Are we voting on the grounds of obviousness? This question is well-written.

Comment: Guys Please when you downvote you are forbidding me from asking further questions in a while. :/

Comment: @hamzakeurti: That's not an immediate concern of a Q & A site, unfortunately.

Comment: @Bathsheba: I understand that. But I find it unfair to downvote me for asking something I did not understand, looked for and could not find a satisfying answer. And I believe other c++ beginners would find this Q&A educating, just as it was for me just now...

Comment: @hamzakeurti: I personally don't agree with the downvoting on this question, as I've already mentioned. But you *could* improve it by writing a compilable example.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Now that you mention it, I never thought it was important to provide a compilable version.. I will consider this in the future, Thanks!

Comment: @hamzakeurti: You should do it here, and in any previous questions you've asked. Also don't change a question materially (as you have done in your recent edit), as that invalidates answers.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Aoutch! I did not know that either! I'll work on it now!

Comment: thats a nice example why `...` has no place in a [mcve] ;). Why do you want to declare the reference `a` upfront and pass it to some other function when anyhow you later want to assign the last element to it? Seems like you want to use the same variable for two unrelated things, just dont do that.

Comment: @tobi303: Thanks for the link, it is exactly what I needed to provide better asked questions. As for the use of the reference pre-declaration, the function will assign a different reference to a depending on if there is an element in a_vector with matching id, if found it assigns a reference to that element, if not it gives a reference to a newly created element which brings us to me trying to give this newly created element the corresponding id.

Comment: I will edit the question, according to the post @tobi303 shared and all the advices Bathsheba gave me, in two hours as I will be out of office for a while.

Comment: not sure but maybe you better ask that as a new question, because "how to use `back()`?" already has been answered here while "how to conditionally assign to a reference?" is a different question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
A a;
a = a_vector.back();
```

Here you're copy-assigning `a_vector.back()` to `a`. This is not a reference, so modifying `a` will not modify the element inside the vector.

You want this instead:

```
A& a = a_vector.back();
```

---

If you cannot immediately initialize  your reference with `a_vector.back()`, consider using a pointer...

```
A* a;

// ...

a = &a_vector.back();

// ... 

something(*a);
```

...or an index:

```
std::size_t a_idx;

// ...

a_idx = a_vector.size() - 1;

// ... 

something(a_vector[a_idx]);
```

- The pointer will work fine if you know that the vector won't get resized. If the vector resize, iterators and pointers will be invalidated.
- The index will work fine even if the vector gets resized, as long as the elements are not removed/shifted around.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But can we do the reference declaration and the assignment of the reference in two different statements? (See question EDIT)

Comment: @hamzakeurti: see my EDIT.

Answer (score 4):

You need a reference to the object:

```
auto& a = a_vector.back();
```

Or, in a more compact manner:

```
a_vector.back().id = 2;
```

---

You're holding a copy, not the original object. That is why the object in vector does not get modified.

---

Answer to edited question: references can be assigned only during declaration. What you want is probably `std::reference_wrapper`, but anyway, please don't use it unless you have to.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But can we do the reference declaration and the assignment of the reference in two different statements? (See question EDIT)